# Declare an array with variable width

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I know array width is assigned at compile time, but I have a scenario where I need to set array width based on a constraint. What are the alternate ways of setting a variable array width? In the below sample code, I need to declare an array based on the variable `width` in the class `ABC`.

```
class ABC;
    rand int width;

    constraint c_w {width == 32;}
endclass

module tb();
    initial begin
        ABC cfg = new();
        bit [(32*cfg.width)-1:0] array; //Error
        array = 'h123;
        $display("array=0x%h", array);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

There are number of different way of dealing with this depending on what you plan to do with `array`.

Since you seem to want to multiples of 32-bits, you can declare a dynamic array of 32-bit words.

```
module tb();
ABC cfg;
bit [31:0] array[];

initial begin
    cfg = new();
    assert(cfg.randomize();
    array = new[cfg.width];
    assert(std::randomize(array)
    foreach (array[i]) $display("array[%0i]=0x%h", i,array);
end
endmodule
```

Another option is declaring `array` as packed with the largest possible width, then mask out the unneeded bits.